# Android publishProgress is not being called

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

After searching through similar threads, still wasn't able to figure out the problem in my AsyncTask code.

The `publishProgress` method is never activated, checked it with breakpoints.

Here is the AsyncTask class:

```
public class workerThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private int completed;

    protected void onProgressUpdate(int... arg0) {

        progressBar.setProgress(arg0[0]);
        statusView.setText(String.format("Completed %d", arg0[0]));

        return;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(Void... unused) {

        completed = 0;
        progressBar.setProgress(completed);

        return;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        int l;

        for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
            for (int n=0; n < 500; ++n) {
                for (int j=0; j <5000; ++j) {
                    l = n*j*i;
                }
            }
            completed++;
            publishProgress(completed);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is the execution from the main UI thread:

```
new workerThread().execute();
```

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: As a side note, Class names should start with an uppercase letter by convention.

Comment: You are calling publish progress once all your loops finish, means at the end!

Comment: Actually, it should be called 100 times, there is still a loop around that.

Comment: Ah I missed the outer one, bad at pattern type loops :D

Comment: `onProgressUpdate(Integer... arg0)` Use `Integer` instead of `int`

Comment: Thanks Pratik, that solved it. Noted also the Class names :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the AsyncTask basic structure given by the documentation.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    int count = urls.length;
    long totalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

The only difference between this and yours its the mismatch between the parameters that inner functions of the AsyncTask class expects and the ones that you have declared.

You declared `protected void onProgressUpdate(int... arg0)` but your class is expecting to get a `Integer` value instead of a primitive type `int`.

Try to change it and run again.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks, changing to Integer sorted it!